# listen back on -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Example ([short audio clip](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1vsdLvTXTkj)):

Transcript:

> — Yep. So, in this episode Harp and I are gonna share our predictions about the future with you.
>   — Hmm, I'm so intrigued.
>   — So, this will be an interesting episode to **listen back on** in a couple of years and see if our predictions became true.
>   — Yes, we'll see how right we were.

I don't know how I should understand the phrasing *listen back on*. In particular, I have a problem with the preposition *on* there. Why not say *listen back to*? How can you listen on something? Is that even correct English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The well-known phrase that "should" be there is *look back on* - and *to look back on* means to reminisce, or to review/consider the memories of past events, or the experience or what was learned from such past events.

I haven't heard *listen back on* before, but it would be an colorful form of *look back on* if the person/being reminiscing was blind or didn't have a sense of vision.  So it's probably a writer being playful with well-known phrases, or doing the most logical thing if this is an audio-only show.